# Python : Is there a way to interactively draw a graph in NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Suppose I have to create a graph with 15 nodes and certain nodes. Instead of feeding the nodes via coding, can the draw the nodes and links using mouse on a figure? Is there any way to do this interactively?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Sorry.  In principle it could be possible to create a GUI which interfaces with networkx (and maybe some people have), but it's not built directly into networkx.